# Failed to store PAT using keyring; falling back to file storage

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-cli

### Goal/Problem

I want to create a command to manage pipelines on azure devops.
Therefore, I created a PAT-token with the privileges for that.
But when I execute the pipeline command, the output told me that a authentication is required.

```bash
$ az pipelines list --org https://dev.azure.com/company-name--project project --top 2
The requested resource requires user authentication: https://dev.azure.com/company-name/project/_apis/build/Definitions?queryOrder=none&$top=2
```

If I click on that link I can log in my account and get the output.

I know that there are 3 ways to login in devops. I tried all of them but they didn't work. Here is one of them.

```bash
$ az devops login --organization https://dev.azure.com/company-name --verbose
Token:
Creating connection with personal access token.
Failed to store PAT using keyring; falling back to file storage.
You can clear the stored credential by running az devops logout.
Refer https://aka.ms/azure-devops-cli-auth to know more on sign in with PAT.
Command ran in 5.744 seconds (init: 0.205, invoke: 5.539)
```

### Specs

```bash
$ az --version
azure-cli                         2.44.1

core                              2.44.1
telemetry                          1.0.8

Extensions:
azure-devops                      0.25.0
interactive                        0.4.6

Dependencies:
msal                              1.20.0
azure-mgmt-resource             21.1.0b1

Python location '/opt/az/bin/python3'
Extensions directory '/home/fabkli/.azure/cliextensions'

Python (Linux) 3.10.8 (main, Jan 10 2023, 15:48:34) [GCC 11.3.0]

Legal docs and information: aka.ms/AzureCliLegal


Your CLI is up-to-date.
```

I am logged in with a ServicePrincipal (`az login --identity`) and also that has the privileges on the pipelines.

Can somebody help me the log me in to use the devops extension of the azure-cli? Thanks

Comment: I saw that another guy has the same problem and the same version (https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/25138). Maybe its a bug in this version.

Comment: The new issue in another repo -> https://github.com/Azure/azure-devops-cli-extension/issues/1349